# adapting this code to mine? (android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, android-spinner

so basically I have 6 spinner with 6 edittext and a button, and when I click the button I want all the selected element in spinners + edit text to go in a textview(display).I have this java code to make that, but the code doesnt fit my actual code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Affichage extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_affichage);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.afficher);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent!=null)
    {
        String day = intent.getStringExtra("day");
        String month = intent.getStringExtra("month");
        String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");

        textView.setText(day + "\n" + month + "\n" + text);

    }
    else
    {
        textView.setText("Intent is null");
    }
}}
```

In this code, spinner were defined like this:

```
String[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
        "Friday", "Saturday" };
```

But I define my spinner in an xml file(mainactivity.xml) like this for example:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner2"
        android:entries="@array/Products" />
```

And I populate the spinner this way, in an array,in xml file:

```
<array name="Products">
<item>p1</item>
<item>p2</item>
<item>p3</item>
</array>
```

So how to adapt the first code to the way im defining spinner?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) a spinner can be set up like this:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I can't see any spinner in your onCreate().
Assuming that your array xml is located in the resource folder and wrapped by the resource tags, it should be something like

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.Products, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To handle user selections you need to set up an onItemSelectedListener. The documentation also demonstrates that.

Comment: Im really new to android(beginner) and I dont understand what you mean; what are those 2 layout? I have 1 layout for my spinner+edittext and 1 layout for a big texview to put the elements from spinners and edittexts in it

Comment: `simple_spinner_item and simple_spinner_dropdown_item` are standard layout files that define the look of the spinner and its dropdown items. Check the documentation, it's described there. When you say you've got 2 layouts I assume you mean your activity layout file with the textedit and the spinner item?